# xsl attribute referencing in the same xsl:template scope

Tags: java, xslt

```
<xsl:if test="$person/name/first != '' ">
    <xsl:attribute name="FirstName">
        <xsl:value-of select="$person/name/first"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$person/name/middle != '' " >
    <xsl:attribute name="MiddleInitial">
        <xsl:variable name="middle" select="$person/name/middle" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($middle, 1, 1)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$person/name/last != '' ">
    <xsl:attribute name="LastName">
        <xsl:value-of select="$person/name/last"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Can i do the following where MiddleInitial value is only 1 char long:

```
<xsl: if test="((FirstName != '') and (MiddleInitial != '') and (LastName != ''))">
    <xsl:variable name="fullName" select="normalize-space(concat($FirstName,$MiddleInitial,$LastName))"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($fullName)>30"><xsl:value-of select="substring($fullName,1,30)"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$fullName"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You are showing two snippets of code without any context, and ...? The only thing I can say with certainty that there's no `&&` operator in XSLT.

Comment: Confusing that in your first code fragment, FirstName, MiddleInitial etc are the names of attributes that you are creating, but in the second, they are either or both of element names in the input and variable names. Incidentally, even in the US, this notion that names can be reduced to firstname, middle initial and lastname is such a laughable stereotype that it ought to be banned on ethnic diversity grounds.

Comment: For best response, please post (1) One or more test cases, each test case consisting of (1.1) Sample input document; and (1.2) Expected output from that input; (2) Rules about the structure of input documents; (3) Rules of transformation; (4) XSLT version (1.0, 2,0 or 3.0); (5) XSLT processor vendor; and (6) What you have tried so far.